# Rails Devise New Registration Form Textfield Not Functioning Properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After setting up Devise, I want to add a field to store a user's username. I started by adding the migration:

```
class AddUsernametoUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

  add_column :users, :uname, :string

  end
end
```

I then added this code to the existing sign up form:

```
  <div class="form-group">

        <%= f.label :uname %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :uname, class: "form-control" %>
        <p style="font-size: 12px; margin-top:5px;"><i>(This will be displayed to    other users.)</i></p>
    </div>
```

And added the new field to the user model for form validation:

```
validates :uname, presence: true
```

The problem I'm having is that no matter what I put in the username textfield, I get the validation error that there is no data in the field. If I remove the validation code, it lets me submit the form but adds nothing to the uname column.

I've followed this exact same process in the past when adding a name field and had no problems, not sure what's going on now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your controller or model, depending on wether you are on Rails 3 or Rails 4.

In Rails 3, you would need an `attr_accessor` on the user model.

In Rails 4 you would need to follow the instructions listed [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters).